# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize List

Tags: c#, ssis

Estou tantendo Deserializar um arquivo JSON, podem estou tendo este erro
"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsoleApp1.Program+detalhe]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly."

```
{
"detalhes": [],
"subdetalhes": {
    "carro": {
        "descricao": "carro",
        "detalhes": [
            {
                "codigo": 00000,
                "descricao": "CREDENCIADO",
                "data": "2019-01-15 01:05:36",
                "ticket": "00000",
                "mensal": true,
                "terminal": {
                    "codigo": 5,
                    "tipo": ""
                },
                "setor": {
                    "descricao": "ESTACIONAMENTO"
                },
                "tipoVeiculo": {
                    "descricao": "AUTOMOVEL"
                },
                "tipoServico": {
                    "descricao": "COMUM"
                }
            },
            }
        ],
        "subdetalhes": {},
        "quantidade": 1745
    },
    "caminhao": {
        "descricao": "caminhao",
        "detalhes": [],
        "subdetalhes": {},
        "quantidade": 0
    },
    "moto": {
        "descricao": "moto",
        "detalhes": [],
        "subdetalhes": {},
        "quantidade": 0
    }
},
"quantidade": 1745

}
```

Esse é o arquivo JSON, porem ele tem mais de um [] e não estou conseguindo criar classes para deserializar

```
      public class detalhe{

      public List<Entrada> entrada { get; set; }

      }

      public class Entrada{

        public int codigo { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public int ticket { get; set; }
        public bool mensal { get; set; }
      }
```

````
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxr/pxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/51/20190101/xxxxxx/?detalhe=true");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            //Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

            var records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<detalhe>>(response.Content);


            foreach (var r in records)

            {
                Console.Read();
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }
        } ```
````

Comment: As suas classes não coincidem em nada com o json apresentado... como você espera realizar essa operação sem fazer o mapeamento manual?

Comment: Podes mapear a tua classe com a ajuda de serviços online, http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro o `Json` que você apresentou está errado. Essa última `}` está sobrando

```
"detalhes": [
    {
        "codigo": 00000,
        "descricao": "CREDENCIADO",
        "data": "2019-01-15 01:05:36",
        "ticket": "00000",
        "mensal": true,
        "terminal": {
            "codigo": 5,
            "tipo": ""
        },
        "setor": {
            "descricao": "ESTACIONAMENTO"
        },
        "tipoVeiculo": {
            "descricao": "AUTOMOVEL"
        },
        "tipoServico": {
            "descricao": "COMUM"
        }
    },
    } <----
```

Agora se você não sabe como refletir esse json em suas respectivas classes para a serialiazação e desserialização, você pode utilizar o Visual Studio para isso... basta copiar o texto do `Json` e utlizar o "Colar Especial"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado para o Json corrigido seriam as classes abaixo... será criado o `Rootobject` e as estruturas posteriores, partindo disso você vai corrigindo para para adequar de fato a reflexão partindo desse ponto inicial. Você conseguirá um resultado muito melhor se para realizar essa operação utilizar um documento 100% preenchido, como vieram itens vazios ele acaba criando as duplicatas, como o `Subdetalhes1`, `Subdetalhes2`, `Subdetalhes3`...

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public object[] detalhes { get; set; }
    public Subdetalhes subdetalhes { get; set; }
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
}

public class Subdetalhes
{
    public Carro carro { get; set; }
    public Caminhao caminhao { get; set; }
    public Moto moto { get; set; }
}

public class Carro
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public Detalhe[] detalhes { get; set; }
    public Subdetalhes1 subdetalhes { get; set; }
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
}

public class Subdetalhes1
{
}

public class Detalhe
{
    public int codigo { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
    public string ticket { get; set; }
    public bool mensal { get; set; }
    public Terminal terminal { get; set; }
    public Setor setor { get; set; }
    public Tipoveiculo tipoVeiculo { get; set; }
    public Tiposervico tipoServico { get; set; }
}

public class Terminal
{
    public int codigo { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
}

public class Setor
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Tipoveiculo
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Tiposervico
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
}

public class Caminhao
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public object[] detalhes { get; set; }
    public Subdetalhes2 subdetalhes { get; set; }
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
}

public class Subdetalhes2
{
}

public class Moto
{
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public object[] detalhes { get; set; }
    public Subdetalhes3 subdetalhes { get; set; }
    public int quantidade { get; set; }
}

public class Subdetalhes3
{
}
```